# Python Installing a site package in Win 10 but unable to use it

Tags: python-3.x

I successfully installed both pykrige and can see it under site packages in explorer, but cannot see them in jupyter notebook and cannot import them.

Installed c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykrige-1.4.dev0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for PyKrige==1.4.dev0
Finished processing dependencies for PyKrige==1.4.dev0

[Site package dir shows that pykrige is there under Anaconda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUS98.png)

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pykrige'

Yet, I am unable to import and cannot find it listed in Home of Jupyter browser?
Need guidance as what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: In Jupyter browser, what's the value of `sys.executable`? Is it in the same Anaconda 3 installation, or is it maybe running with some other version of Python on your system?

Answer (score 0):

In researching it more, I discovered I have 2 Anaconda3 installations, one in root c:\, and the other under User/myname. The pip installations go under the User version site-packages whereas the jupyter is running from my root Anaconda. Copying over the installed packages "seemed" to have fixed my problem.